# Update operation not working in Php MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning php and MySql database. I am trying to make payroll management software. In my database both insert & delete operation are executing well but i am facing problem in update operation. Here is my php script :

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    session_start();    
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];
    $term = $_POST['id'];

    //open database
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","#") or die("Couldn't connect");
    mysql_select_db("caselab") or die("Couldn't connect");  
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id='$term'");        
    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);  
    if($count!=0)
    {
        // output data of each row
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
        $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
        $address = strip_tags($_POST['address']);
        $contactinfo = $_POST['contactinfo'];

        if($submit)
        {
            //open database
            $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","#") or die("Couldn't connect");
            mysql_select_db("caselab") or die("Couldn't connect");  

            // Existence Check
            if($name  && $email && $address && $contactinfo)
            {
                $queryreg = mysql_query ("Update users SET username = '$name', email = '$email' , address = '$address' , contactinfo = '$contactinfo' WHERE id = $id");
                    echo ("Congratulations!! Your changes have been saved !! <a href='payroll.html'>Click to go back to home page</a>");        
            }
            else
                echo("Please fill all the details");
        }   
        mysql_close($connect);
    }
    else
        echo("No such employee. Please try again.<a href='payroll.html'>Click to go back to home page</a> ");
?>
</html>
</body>
```

I would be highly thankful if my problem gets resolved.

Comment: Strings need inverted commas/quotation marks

Comment: Sir i have corrected it now. But still my problem is same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why is there a ) before WHERE?

```
Update users SET username = $name, email = $email , address = $address , contactinfo = $contactinfo) WHERE id = $id");
```

Try this:

```
$myqry =  "Update users SET username = '". $name."', email = '".$email."' , address = '".$address."', contactinfo = '".$contactinfo."' WHERE id = ".$id.";
echo($myqry;
$queryreg = mysql_query($myqry);
if .....
```

However, i need reminder you that this is not a good programming method and you need learn how to PDO after you understand the basic query concepts. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I am sorry about that. I have corrected it now. But still data is not updated in database.

Comment: any errors? did you try print out the query statement? there can be so many reasons and it's not easy to debug if you don't have any debug information at hand.

Comment: Sir this is what i tried just now. I edited this just after the queryreg Code:
 $show = mysql_query($connect,$queryreg) or die("Error");
Now i am getting the error:
Warning : mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\harsh\case\update.php on line 32
Error

Comment: You need single quotes for string values. I changed the answer.

Comment: Sorry Sir i tried this also. I am not getting any error now but still the problem is the same. My data is not getting updated in the database.

Comment: @Harsh From your comment, it seems that the connection to the database is what is causing the error `mysql_connect` fails so the content of `$connect` is now `Couldn't connect`. Try checking the username,password,database and host.

Comment: @stefanstojanovski Sir if that had been the case then error message would had been displayed. But i am getting Congratulation message. But the data in the table is not getting updated.

Comment: Have you checked that `$submit` is true so that the query that updated the table is executed? Just put some `echo "$submit is true"` statements to see at what point the code execution stops.

Comment: your statement syntax is correct but it's not using your own data, so the query was executed successfully with no effects.

Comment: @Tim3880 On trying the updated code also, Still the problem remains same. And yes thank you so much for sharing the link. I will surely switch to PDO as soon as possible.

Comment: @stefanstojanovski Sir on echoing the message "$submit is true". I am getting this on the screen : Update is trueCongratulations!! Your changes have been saved !! and then the link to go back.

Comment: try echo your query statement to see what is really you got.